# Magento 2 get the minimum order quantity on single product page?

Tags: magento2, orders

I am trying to get minimum order quantity in single product page. If someone want to purchase the product and put the quantity of the product which he/she want to buy.

But **if the quantity is less than the minimum order quantity** **then there will generate a warning**, in which the minimum amount of quantity is mentioned. For single product page i am using `view.phtml` file which is a custom created file and i want to get minimum order quantity of particular product in this file.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: you can set from admin in product details page  for minimum qty

Comment: I am asking for get the quantity. Already set from backend. minimum order quantity want to show in frontend .

Comment: @Yudi Check my updated answer.

Comment: @chirag this is not what i was asking. that's why....

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Store > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Option**
[image]

in that set `Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart` it will automatically display minimum quantity on your product page.

[image]

You can also **set minimum quantity** for a particular product. go to **Product > Edit Product > Advanced Setting >Advanced Inventory**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @chirag. It will allow minimum 5 items in our cart. But If i have simple product associated with configurable product, in which only one simple product have minimum order quantity and other don't have. Then in that case if customer want to purchase other simple product (without have minimum order quantity). Then for those product also minimum order quantity will again 5. And i don't want that. I want to get the minimum quantity which i have set to particular product from backend not for all of the product.

Comment: check my updated answer