# How to set qty number to add to cart on product page

Tags: product, product-list, product-view, quantity

How to set certain number when the product page loads up.
Default level when you click on a product the add to basket quarry is always one how to change that to different value for each store.
I know we can put the value in phtml but we can always change it to one if we enter lower number

I want to add a check of customer change the new value e.g from 2 to 1 I want a error to be shown

I was planning to override list.phtml

Magento 2 I am after

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what Magento version

Something like this should work with Magento 1

https://www.magespider.com/how-to-add-quantity-box-on-product-list-page-in-magento/

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

```
<?php $product_id=$_product->getId() ?>
<?php $base_url=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);?>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="<?php echo $product_id ?>" maxlength="12" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"></input>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onClick="addToCart('<?php echo $product_id ?>','<?php echo $base_url?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addToCart(pid,purl)
{
    var qty=document.getElementById(pid).value;
    var action=purl+"checkout/cart/add/product/"+pid+"/qty/"+qty;
    window.location=action;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for that and I am after magento 2 I want to create a module. I know we can change it from admin area by changing product stock option but still I can change the value

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of another answer which involves no programming.

You could create a group product and assign a single product to that group.

Like this product.  This is Magento 2.  But Magento 1 works the same.

https://magento.nublue.co.uk/set-of-sprite-yoga-straps.html

But with just one

Comment: This product page shows 0 as the starting qty I want to change it to 2 and if customer try to lower it to 1 give a error message

Comment: There is this on the cart https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/148398/70343

Comment: That’s for all store I have 7 stores and I am just trying to add it for 1 of them that’s why I was planning to create a module but not 100 percent sure if it’s a good idea

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So the current value is 0. I want to change it to 2 or higher, incase if someone (customer) put it 1 don’t allow them to add to basket

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I believe this is what you want

- Edit a simple product
- Click Advanced Inventory
- Change 'Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart' option

Comment: I want to edit any product. On my stores I have simple and configurable product so I want to set the starting qty value to be 2 and if customer try to put 1 as the value give an error

Comment: If for a specific store scope you will have to change to that store

Comment: Still not showing the error, when I do it through admin and I wasn’t aware if I could do it by store scope

Comment: Have you got inventory management turned off?

Comment: How do I check this and I have checked now I can’t change the minimum qty allowed in shopping cart option in scope store

Comment: Store > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory, plus check individual products

Comment: It’s on for me product stock options and I have checked individual product

Comment: I don’t want to add it individually for products